# How to change textColor or MDCTextInputControllerOutlined

Tags: ios, swift, material-components-ios

I am using `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined` and I want change textColor to white I have tried many ways but I can not able to change textColor below is my code:

```
var emailTextFieldController : MDCTextInputControllerOutlined?
emailTextFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: txtEmailAddress)
emailTextFieldController?.borderStrokeColor = UIColor.white
emailTextFieldController?.activeColor = UIColor.white
emailTextFieldController?.inlinePlaceholderColor = UIColor.white
emailTextFieldController?.textInputClearButtonTintColor = .white
emailTextFieldController?.floatingPlaceholderActiveColor = UIColor.white
```

**How do I change text`MDCTextInputControllerOutlined`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

txtEmailAddress.textColor = UIColor.white